# XML XPath problems

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am new to Xpath, practically only first looked at it today, and im having some issues with the XPath not loading images defined in the XML.

So far I have:

```
<page name = "home"><br />
<image>
        <imagehome1>
            <imge>resp.jpg</imge><br />
            <class>right</class>
        </imagehome1>
        <imagehome2>
            <imge></imge><br />
            <class>right</class>
        </imagehome2>
        <imagehomebot>
            <imge>cfr.png</imge><br />
            <class>bottom</class>
        </imagehomebot>
    </image>
</page>
```

As you can see i am defining 2 images, 1 in imagehome1 and 1 in imagehomebot, however my XPath code only displays the image from imagehomebot..... and I have no idea why.

My PHP XPath code is:

```
<? 
                $nodes = $dom->xpath('/content/page/image/imagehome1');
                if (count($nodes) > 0) {
                    if(!(string)$nodes[0]->imge){
                        $class = "";}
                    else{
                    $class3 = (string)$nodes[0]->class;
                    $img3 = (string)$nodes[0]->imge;}
                }
            ?>
    <div class="<? echo $class ?>">
        <img src="imgs/<? echo $img1 ?>" />
    </div>

    <? 
                $nodes = $dom->xpath('/content/page/image/imagehome2');
                if (count($nodes) > 0) {
                    if(!(string)$nodes[0]->imge){
                        $class = "";}
                    else{
                    $class3 = (string)$nodes[0]->class;
                    $img3 = (string)$nodes[0]->imge;}
                }
            ?>

    <div class="<? echo $class ?>">
        <img src="imgs/<? echo $img2 ?>" />
    </div>

    </div>


    <div id="box2">

    <? 
                $nodes = $dom->xpath('/content/page/image/imagehomebot');
                if (count($nodes) > 0) {
                    if(!(string)$nodes[0]->imge){
                        $class = "";}
                    else{
                    $class3 = (string)$nodes[0]->class;
                    $img3 = (string)$nodes[0]->imge;}
                }
            ?>

<div class="<? echo $class3 ?>">
        <img src="imgs/<? echo $img3 ?>" />
    </div>
```

All help is much appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: just had another quick look over my code and I think I know why, damn copy and paste haha...

Comment: Do all those images exist? What does the HTML output look like?

Comment: And where's the code that actually shows the imagehomebot image?

Comment: It has probably to do with that '/' missing after the 'imgs' folder, but since it has magically appeared now, your problem may be solved, right? :)

Comment: nope none of the above, if you look closely as the numbering scheme the variables dont match up lol. if you take a look at my OP EDIT. I've been copying and pasting lots which is why that happened

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Setting $img3 and outputting $img2. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to process all the nodes containing imge nodes the same.

Try

'/content/page/image/*[imge]'

to get imagehome1, imagehome2 and imagehomebot with one xpath.  If you want to limit the nodes to the ones having an actual string it might be something like

/content/page/image/*[imge/text()]

The expression in "[]" is the "predicate" that specifies criteria in relation to the "context" node just in front of it ("*") which says get all child nodes of image.  (I did that because they were named differently.)